# matlab differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have followed the tutorial on http://www.mit.edu/people/abbe/matlab/ode.html and prepared a function as follows:

```
function dxy = diffxy(xy)
%
%split xy into variables in our equations
%
    x = xy(1);
xdot = xy(2);
y = xy(3);
%
% define the derivatives of these variables from equations
%
xdot = xdot;
ydot     = 3*x + 2*y + 5;
xdoubledot = 3 - ydot + 2*xdot;
%
%return the derivatives in dxy in the right order
%
dxy = [xdot; xdoubledot; ydot]
end
```

When I call it using

```
[T, XY] = ode45('diffxy',0,10,[0 1 0])
```

I get an error

```
??? Error using ==> diffxy
Too many input arguments.
```

I also tried

```
XY= ode45(@diffxy,[0 10],[0;1;0])
```

Anybody have any idea?

Problem solved. time should be considered also as a parameter. New function definition:

```
function dxy = diffxy(**t**,xy)
```

THANKS

Comment: The function you call with ode45 must accept two arguments. See the documentation for details.

Comment: yep problem solved

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer rather than editing it into the question. Otherwise the question will remain open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting the answer edited into the question*

Problem solved. time should be considered also as a parameter. New function definition:

> function dxy = diffxy(t,xy)